# Displaying results from a database using a dropdownmenu

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a question about how to retrieve data from a database using a dropdownlist in ASP.NET .(I apologize for the spaghetti code that I have posted here, however it is the easiest to write and this is just a concept I'm trying to understand).

I'm always a little queasy about asking questions here, but, this is something I just can't solve for some reason. I've already asked my peers and Google'd for help and insight regarding this matter and I have come up empty-handed.

So, let me get into the problem. 
I have made a simple page with a dropdownlist, a label, and an image control.
The dropdownlist is populated with entries from a database I've built.
The code follows:

```
public partial class view_products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private static SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);
   private SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("sp_itemTable", sqlconn);

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 //the query is SELECT * FROM <DataBase Name>
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5;
    try
    {
        if (sqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            sqlconn.Open();
        }
        dt.Load(sqlcomm.ExecuteReader());

        sqlconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Response.Write(exception.Message);
    }
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "pname";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "pid";//pid is PK in my DataBase Table
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

The list populates after the page is loaded.
Now, I want to take the value (ie, pid) selected from the dropdownlist and use it to get records from the database.

The code follows:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4;
    try 
    {
        if (sqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            sqlconn.Open();
        }
        dt.Load(sqlcomm.ExecuteReader());

        sqlconn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Response.Write(exception.Message);
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["pname"].ToString();
        Image1.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[0]["pimage"].ToString();
    }
    else
        Response.Write("Data Retrieval Failed!");
 }
}
```

Here lies the problem.
I can't seem to get this part of the code working. The data isn't displayed. Even though autopostback is enabled in the dropdownlist. And I think I've developed code myopia from working on this for some time now.

Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: getting any exceptions or direct "Data Retrieval Failed" ? And also, have you put break point on your `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` method to check on every page load it is being fired with default selected index of drop down list and perform remaining logic for that Selected index only (causing un-expected behavior).

Comment: @Amit None. No exceptions or direct "Data Retrieval Failed".Also, I have used the breakpoint and it doesn't come up with anything.

Comment: Then i would suggest you to put break point and debug (or put logs). I have doubt that your `DropDownList_SeletedIndexChanged` method is being called multiple times (one with your desired drop down selection and then via page load where your are initiating your drop down again - so selected index will be changed to default and fire that event again). You better try debugging

Comment: I put the whole part of the code in Page_Load even in a 
    if(!IsPostBack) {}

bracket.But the same problem persists. No errors or logs from running it.
Edit: Made some changes because made some errors posting this comment.

Comment: Just Confirming, you have debugged and according to that, on drop down selected index changed, you are getting no errors and some values from database too, (must be assigning proper values to `Label1` and `Image1`). Your break point on this event is not getting hit second(unwanted) time. and still you are not getting proper values in display? If once they are set with proper values and still you are seeing wrong values, they might have being set from different place too [If you are not at all able to see Label and Image, their visibility maybe set to false - but that is very less probable]

Comment: yes. That is it.

Comment: I have made some changes to see if my code is at fault here. I have taken the code from my dropdownlist_changed event and put it in a button1_clicked event. The code works. The image control shows the image and the label changes its text.

Comment: So, now you figured it out what was wrong before ?

Comment: No. But the code works when I'm doing it through the button. So that would suggest that it was the dropdownmenu that was causing the problem. I have no clue as to what.

Comment: Put the log (showing selected index) on very first line of `DropDownList_SeletedIndexChanged` , perform selection from dropdown. Update your code on question accordingly and show us the log you got!